# Error when concatenate in macro gcc preprocessor

Tags: gcc, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I'm getting an error when I try to use ## in macro this is what I try to make:

With this defines:

```
#define PORT 2
#define PIN 3
```

I want that preprocessor generates:

```
PM2.3=1
```

when I call a macro like this:

```
SetPort(PORT,PIN)
```

Then, I see that I can make the substitution PORT and PIN at the same time that concatenation, then I think I must to use 2 defines:

```
#define SetP2(PORT,PIN) PM##PORT.PIN = 1
#define SetPort(PORT,PIN) SetP2(PORT,PIN)
```

but I get an error on:

```
#define PIN 3  --> expected identifier before numeric constant
```

and a warning on:

```
SetPort(PORT,PIN) --> Syntax error
```

Any idea?

Comment: How are you invoking gcc?  `gcc -E <source.c>`, or something else?  Which version of gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$ cat portpin.c
#define PORT 2
#define PIN 3

#define SetP2(prefix,prt) prefix ## prt
#define SetPort(prt,pn) SetP2(PM,prt).pn = 1

SetPort(PORT,PIN)
$ gcc -E portpin.c 
# 1 "portpin.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "portpin.c"


PM2. 3 = 1
$
```

I don't know how important it is for there to be no space between the `.` and the `3`, but the preprocessor seems to want to insert it.

UPDATE:

Actually I tried your original code, and it seems to produce the same result, so my answer above is probably not much use to you.

UPDATE 2:

It turns out the OP is expecting the pre-processor to generate `PM2.no3=1` and not `PM2.3=1`.  This can easily be done as follows:

```
$ cat portpin.c
#define PORT 2
#define PIN 3

#define SetP2(PORT,PIN) PM##PORT.no##PIN=1
#define SetPort(PORT,PIN) SetP2(PORT,PIN)

SetPort(PORT,PIN)
$ gcc -E portpin.c
# 1 "portpin.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "portpin.c"

PM2.no3=1
$
```

Comment: Real problem is space between `PM2.` and `3`. It happens because macro expansion leaves spaces between tokens. There are a number of ways to work around, but all them are failing, because `PM2.3` isn't a valid preprocessor token

Comment: Then, there is no way to implement that?

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov - yes, this is a good point.  I think the question is what does the OP intend to do with `PM2.3=1` once the preprocessor has (hypothetically) generated this.  Is this supposed to be legal c which can be fed to the c compiler proper?

Comment: Yes, `PM2.3=1` is perfectly valid for compiler (is for use with bit instructions in some hardware), I need to use the part `2.3`to some registers: `PM2.3=1`,`PIM2.3=1`, `POM2.3=0` this is why I want to use ## to not declare all registers, only the port and pin...

Comment: Can you give some more context of the code?  Is the statement `PM2.3=1` intended to be regular c, or is it an assembly statement  for some specific hardware?  I think the *c* preprocessor can only be expected to generate valid c code, and not hardware-specific assembly code to go in an assembler directive.

Comment: It's not assembler, but I don't know if it's any kind of specific c for this hardware, the definition of PM2 is `#define PM2 (*(volatile union un_pm2 *)0xFFF22).BIT`and for un_pm2 `union un_pm2 {unsigned char pm2; __BITS8 BIT;};`

Comment: I finally found the problem and solution, really the instruction is not PM2.3 but PM2.no3, then, as there is not an "integer", its a typedef and now `PM##PORT.no##PIN=1` works fine, thanks for your help

Comment: Ok that makes more sense now - I'm glad you got this to work.  I updated my answer with this info.